# When to use expand() and/or sub-selects

Tags: orientdb

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me the difference between the following three queries and why only the last one works.

```
select out() from #1:0 where @class instanceof 'BaseClass'
select expand(out()) from #1:0 where @class instanceof 'BaseClass'
select from (select expand(out()) from #1:0) where @class instanceof 'BaseClass'
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the where condition is not well applied in the first 2 cases.
The first one out() returns only a collection of record id,
With the second one the array is expanded and transformed in a collection of document, but i think the where condition is applied before the expand so like case 1 does not work.

If you prefer to not use subquery you can always do

```
select expand(out()[ @class = 'BaseClass']) from #1:0
```